# How to make CALayer border alpha value different with the bgcolor

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quartz-core

I've got an UIView that has a layer with alpha value of 0.5 and white background color. And I need to have a border with the same white but the alpha value of 1. Unfortunately, AFAIK the border 's alpha value is always the same with the bgcolor's. So my questions are:

1. Can I make the alpha of the border different with the bgcolor?
2. If I can't, do you have any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make the alpha of the border different with the bgcolor?

Yes. You could do something like this:

```
CALayer * firstLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];

[firstLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

firstLayer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
firstLayer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
firstLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
```

Another approach would be to have a layer inside another layer of the same size. Give the outer layer the border thickness you want and make sure it's opacity is 100%. The second layer should have the fractional opacity:

```
CALayer * firstLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
CALayer * secondLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];

[firstLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[secondLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[firstLayer addSublayer:secondLayer];

firstLayer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
firstLayer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

secondLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
secondLayer.opacity = 0.8f;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:firstLayer];
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This should just change the border color and alpha only.

`[self.yourView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];` You can of course change the RGB values to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6].CGColor;
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
```